# EWS The required attribute 'Traversal' is missing

Tags: exchangewebservices, traversal

I have a problem whit EWS (*Exchange Webservice*)

#### I send an request for `FindFolders`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:M="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" soap12:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:T="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
 <soap12:Body>
  <M:FindFolder>
   <request SOAP-ENC:id="1" xsi:type="M:FindFolder" Traversal="Deep">
    <FolderShape xsi:nil="true"/>
    <IndexedPageFolderView SOAP-ENC:id="2" xsi:type="T:IndexedPageViewType" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning"/>
    <ParentFolderIds xsi:nil="true"/>
   </request>
   <Impersonation xsi:nil="true"/>
   <S2SAuth xsi:nil="true"/>
   <MailboxCulture xsi:type="xsd:string">de-DE</MailboxCulture>
   <RequestVersion SOAP-ENC:id="3" xsi:type="T:RequestServerVersion"   Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
  </M:FindFolder>
 </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

#### and get following xml from server

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soap11:Header>
      <t:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="8" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="245" MinorBuildNumber="0" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
     </soap11:Header>
     <soap11:Body>
      <soap11:Fault>
       <faultcode>soap11:Client</faultcode>
       <faultstring>The request failed schema validation: The required attribute 'Traversal' is missing.</faultstring>
       <detail>
        <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode>
        <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">

The required attribute 'Traversal' is missing.

        </e:Message>
        <e:Line xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">2
        </e:Line>
        <e:Position xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">446
        </e:Position>
       </detail>
      </soap11:Fault>
     </soap11:Body>
    </soap11:Envelope>
```

So why the Server say that Traversal is missing ?

(*I also have tested it with the `T:Traversal = Deep`   T: for the namespaceentry for the types*)

Can someone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Traversal` is required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa564962%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) on the `FindFolder` element. Try changing it from...

```xml
<M:FindFolder> 
   <!-- ... -->
```

To this...

```xml
<M:FindFolder Traversal="Deep"> 
   <!-- ... -->
```

The `Traversal` attribute [must adhere to the following XSD schema](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jasig/portlet/CalendarPortlet/2.0.0/CalendarPortlet-2.0.0-javadoc.jar!/com/microsoft/exchange/types/FolderQueryTraversalType.html):

```xml
<simpleType name="FolderQueryTraversalType">
   <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string">
     <enumeration value="Shallow"/>
     <enumeration value="Deep"/>
     <enumeration value="SoftDeleted"/>
   </restriction>
 </simpleType>
```

Comment: i have tryed following constellations

Comment: It sounds like it is case-sensitive (*change DEEP to Deep*). Try using the above edits.

Comment: the casesensitive part was it  now there is a new problem 

  The element 'FindFolder' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages' has invalid child element 'request'. List of possible elements expected: 'FolderShape' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'

Comment: and if i cut out the requestpart the messege comes :  
"The element 'FindFolder' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages' has invalid child element 'FolderShape'. List of possible elements expected: 'FolderShape' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'"

Comment: You need to assign the proper namespace to `FolderShape`. Either use the alias like you did for `FindFolder` (*`M:FolderShape`*), or add it as the default namespace for that element - `<FolderShape xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">`

Answer (score 1):

i have tryed following constellations

```
<M:FindFolder M:Traversal="DEEP>
The request failed schema validation: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages:Traversal' attribute is not declared.

<M:FindFolder T:Traversal="DEEP>
The request failed schema validation: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:Traversal' attribute is not declared.


<M:FindFolder Traversal="DEEP">

The request failed schema validation: The 'Traversal' attribute is invalid - The value 'DEEP' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:FolderQueryTraversalType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```